# How to play/stop default sound automatically in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I want to play and stop the default sound with following rules:

1. If the sound is not playing, let play it in 10 seconds.
2. If the sound is playing, let stop it and play at the first position.

Based on these above rules, I design a function as follows:

```
public MediaPlayer mp =null;
public void playDefaultSound(){
   Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
   try {
       if (mp.isPlaying()) {
       mp.stop();
       mp.release();
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
       }
       mp.start();
       Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
          }
       }, 10000);
       } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

But sometime I still listen two sound are playing (in case of the first sound play and I call the playDefaultSound() function again). Do you think is it correct to delete the `mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);` bellow `mp.release()`? How could I correct the function to satisfy these rules? Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

```
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();   
public void playDefaultSound(){
       Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
       try {
           if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
               mp.seekTo(0);
           } else {
               mp.reset();
               mp.setDataSource(getApplicationNotification(), notification);
               mp.start();
               Handler handler = new Handler();
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       mp.stop();
                       mp.release();
                   }
               }, 10000);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
P.S. - Always see the state diagram or lifecycle of things whenever stuck.

Ref : [Android Media Player State Diagram][1]


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram "MediaPlayer State Diagram"
```

Comment: Thanks. But please check the variable mp. It is final variable, hence it cannot assign in the else state. In additions, the mp.seekTo(0) always go because you assign mp=null at line 3.